# Каким инструментом можно объединять в блоки CSS, JS и HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужен инструмент, способный создавать сайт по методологии [БЭМ](https://ru.bem.info/), а для этого нужно как-то объединять отдельные независимые блоки html кода, к которому применяются стили (причём только к этому конкретному блоку). Например, существует папка:

```
form
  html
    form__header.html
    form__input.html
    form__send-button.html
  css
    styles.css
  js
    scripts.js
```

Нужно её как-то "сжать", чтобы иметь возможность вставлять этот блок с присущими ему стилями и js кодом в любое место на странице.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Существует два инструмента, поддерживающих БЭМ-предметную область, для
>   сборки кода результирующих веб-страниц из отдельных описаний блоков:
>   bem-tools
>   ENB

https://ru.bem.info/technologies/classic/i-bem/overview/#%D1%81%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: Может стоит попробовать React.js ?